# Problem getting the progress of the course in SCORM package

Tags: javascript, scorm, scorm1.2

I'm trying to use [API](https://github.com/gabrieldoty/simplify-scorm) for SCORM. I do not understand some points:

1. When I start the course and perform some tasks of the course. Should I be made progress in the parent window? Is this algorithm embedded in the package?
2. Which parameters must necessarily be passed to SCORM (**cmi.***)

The code in which I'm trying to get values ​​(progress, etc)

```
<script>   
    window.API = new window.simplifyScorm.ScormAPI();
    window.API.apiLogLevel = 1;
    var json = {
        "core": {
            "student_id": "1",
            "student_name": "Student",
            "lesson_status": "incomplete",
        }
    };
    window.API.loadFromJSON(json); 
    window.API.LMSInitialize();
   window.open('file:///D:/testScrom/index.html', 'ScormPlayer');
    setInterval(function(){
        console.log(window.API.cmi.toJSON());
    }, 2000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see above is SCORM 1.2... so `cmi.core.lesson_status` is all the status you get.  It's `passed, failed, not attempted, incomplete or completed`.   Creator of the content really decides which status takes precedence.

As for mastery, thats more in line with your `score.raw` vs the mastery threshold.  So per above the author may of set "complete" but the score could be something the LMS could look at for a level of passed vs. failed.

Answer (score 0):

In SCORM 2004 Edition You can use, '`cmi.progress_measure`' for check progress. but most of SCO not implement  this value.
I also looking  solution for this, please refer my question about this 
[How to Calculate Progress of SCORM content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52396799/how-to-calculate-progress-of-scorm-content/52405823#52405823)