# How to Calculate Progress of SCORM content?

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I'm trying to get a score, and progress from SCORM content (2004 Edition).So far I was able to save CMI values to my database using custom written LMS API.

```
cmi.score.raw--->>0 
cmi.score.max--->>15 
cmi.score.min--->>0 
cmi.score.scaled--->>0
```

I need to know how to calculate the progress of the student, score and grade from above values.
Is there a any specific way or function for calaluclate progress? Or am I missing some value from SCORM?

Answer (score 2):

Generally you would not calculate the score, that is the value that you've shown--`raw` and `scaled`, and is set by the SCO. For progress, 2004 includes the `cmi.progress_measure` value though I think it is only used sporadically and again would be set by the content. There isn't really the concept of a "grade" in SCORM directly. There is the mastery score (or scaled passing score) that is intended to reflect the score required for the SCO to be considered passed. See https://support.scorm.com/hc/en-us/articles/206166246-Setting-the-mastery-score and https://support.scorm.com/hc/en-us/articles/206167026-What-are-the-elements-for-placing-a-passing-score-in-your-SCORM-manifest- for more about this value.

https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/ is a good reference for all of the runtime values.

Comment: 'cmi.progress_measure' data model is grate solution, I need to implement some way to calculate when `cmi.progress_measure` not define, can I know what the relationship between above cmi.score values, How can I map score in to single percentage value ?